# OpenCart 2.1.0.2 Remove Account Links

Tags: opencart2.x

I am searching for a way to remove the "Account" links from the Login, Logout and Customer registration page. I looked in account/register.tpl but do not see any reference to the links?

Any suggestions on where to look?

Comment: Did you checked the layouts?

Comment: Look in `account/header.tpl`

Comment: Find this file. catalog/view/theme/default/template/module/account.tpl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks I found what I was looking for. my theme had an additional file that was being called into the header.tpl file where the links I needed were.